# Override rails method avoiding deep stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've a little problem with my rails app.

I have a cms with two image uploader: main_image and second_image.

When I show a news if second_image exists return second image else return main image.

I need the same behaviour for all the version of my image.

I try with

```
def main_image
 if second_image.file
   return second_image
 else
   return main_image
end
```

but this create a recurrency. How can I fix this?

**Update**

I forgot to add a problem.

My main_image has 4 version (full, square, block and thumb)
My second_image has only 3 version (square, block and thumb)

Main Image version Full is always present.

Comment: add more carrierwave details

Comment: The trivial solution is to provide an appropriately-named method, e.g., `get_image`, that does the actual work. This is also more communicative.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method to something else than `main_image`:

```
def image
  second_image.file ? second_image : main_image
end
```